# CopyMemory Non-POD

Tags: c++

I have structs and vectors that looks like:

```
typedef struct
{
    int SX, SY;
    int X, Y, Z;
    std::vector<Vector3D> Vertices;
    const void* VBOPointer;
} Model;

typedef struct
{
    int X, Y;
    struct
    {
        int VX[4], VY[4];
        int TX[4], VY[4];
    } Quad;
} Item;

std::vector<Item> ListOfItems;
std::vector<Model> ListOfModels;
```

I need to copy these to memory so I can reconstruct them from another program. I've mapped the memory already but then I realized that I cannot use CopyMemory or MemCpy on any of them.

How can I copy it?

Example of how I copy standard data types/structs:

```
struct
{
    int X;
    int Y;
} POD;

//pData is a void pointer to mapped memory given to be by MapFileView..

POD Foo = {100, 50};
long double* Data = static_cast<long double*>(pData);
//Check if Data[1] contains a request command then copy.

CopyMemory(&Data[0], &Foo, sizeof(Foo));
```

Comment: i would write a serialize and deSerialize functions for each class

Comment: Use a third-party - google protobuf comes to mind.

Comment: XDR is a standard way to do this that's totally independent of the machines involved. You could use it in your `Serialize` and `Deserialize` functions as @Gir suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to deal with non-POD data, you need to flatten the structure data into a serialized format that the other app can then parse back into a structure on its end.

Your `ListOfItems` vector can be flattened very easily because its elements are POD data.  Store the `vector` size to an integer, copy that into the buffer, then copy each `Item` afterwards (assuming the buffer is large enough to hold the flattened data):

```
long double* Data = static_cast<long double*>(pData);  
//Check if Data[1] contains a request command then copy.  

unsigned char *Work = static_cast<unsigned char *>(pData);

int number = ListOfItems.size();
CopyMemory(Work, &number, sizeof(int)); 
Work += sizeof(int);

for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
{
    CopyMemory(Work, &ListOfItems[i], sizeof(Item)); 
    Work += sizeof(Item);
}
```

Your `ListOfModels` vector will be little bit harder to flatten since `Model` contains another `vector` in it, but the same concept applies in general:

```
long double* Data = static_cast<long double*>(pData);  
//Check if Data[1] contains a request command then copy.  

unsigned char *Work = static_cast<unsigned char *>(pData);

int number = ListOfModels.size();
CopyMemory(Work, &number, sizeof(int)); 
Work += sizeof(int);

for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
{
    Model &m = ListOfModels[i];

    CopyMemory(Work, &(m.SX), sizeof(int) * 5);
    Work += (sizeof(int) * 5);

    int num = m.Vertices.size();
    CopyMemory(Work, &num, sizeof(int));
    Work += sizeof(int);

    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        Vector3D &v = m.Vertices[j];
        // copy v as needed...
        Work += ...;
    }

    // copy m.VBOPointer as needed ...
    Work += ...;
}
```

What I normally do for something like this is use templates to help simplify the logic and make it easier to read:

```
template<typename T>
void Copy(unsignd char* &Work, const T &value)
{
    CopyMemory(Work, &value, sizeof(T));
}

template<template T>
void Copy(unsigned char* &Work, const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    int number = vec.size();
    Copy(Work, number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
        Copy(Work, vec[i]);
}
```

.

```
long double* Data = static_cast<long double*>(pData);  
//Check if Data[1] contains a request command then copy.  

unsigned char *Work = static_cast<unsigned char *>(pData);
Copy(Work, ListOfItems);
```

.

```
template<>
void Copy<Vector3D>(unsigned char* &Work, const Vector3D &vec)
{
    // copy vec as needed...
    Work += ...;
}

template<>
void Copy<Model>(unsigned char* &Work, const Model &m)
{
    Copy(Work, m.SX);
    Copy(Work, m.SY);
    Copy(Work, m.X);
    Copy(Work, m.Y);
    Copy(Work, m.Z);
    Copy(Work, m.Vertices);

    // copy m.VBOPointer as needed ...
    Work += ...;
}

long double* Data = static_cast<long double*>(pData);  
//Check if Data[1] contains a request command then copy.  

unsigned char *Work = static_cast<unsigned char *>(pData);
Copy(Work, ListOfModels);
```

Comment: `size_t` is more appropriate than `int` (or `unsigned` at the least).

Comment: Sure, `size_t` is appropriate to match `size()` (even better, `std::vector::size_type`). But for serialization purposes, it is best to pick a type that both apps recognize and can agree on regarding byte size, endian, etc. So I would probably be more tempted to use `uint32_t` for handling the byte size, and as long as the apps are on the same machine then endian is not an issue, but it does become an issue if the apps are on different machines communicating with each other (serialization gains you that ability).